# Spark: convert array of arrays to array of strings?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have column with type Array of Arrays I need to get column array of string.

```
+--------------------------+
|field                     |
+--------------------------+
|[[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], []]|
+--------------------------+
```

I need to get:

```
+--------------------------+
|field                     |
+--------------------------+
|["123", "123", ""]        |
+--------------------------+
```

Can I do this in Spark without using UDF?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `transform` higher order function,

```
import spark.implicits._

val df = Seq(Seq(Seq(1,2,3), Seq(1,2,3), Seq())).toDF("field")

df.withColumn("field", expr("transform(field, v->concat_ws('',v))"))
    .show

+------------+
|       field|
+------------+
|[123, 123, ]|
+------------+
```

Comment: That's great! I couldn't find this function. Do you know how I can return array without 1st element? I found how to get first element, but I can't find how to get from this [1, 2, 3] this [2,3]

Comment: You can use transform function in this way - `transform(field, v->slice(v, 2, size(v)))`